# How to convert values of hash into array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to parse elastic search result into a particular format. For that I need to make values of search result hash into array
I have this:

```
hash = {
  "ABC": {
    "attributes": {
      "id": "1",
      "from": "test",
      "to": "something",
    }
  },
  "XYZ": {
    "attributes": {
      "id": "1",
      "from": "value",
      "to": "another value",
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to get to this:

```
"ABC": [
       {
    "attributes": {
      "id": "1",
      "from": "test",
      "to": "something",
                  }
      }],
"XYZ": [
       {
    "attributes": {
      "id": "1",
      "from": "value",
      "to": "another value",
                  }
     }
     ]
```

Simply, hash values should be arrays. Please someone guide me in this.

Comment: The code following "and I want to get this:" is not valid. I assume you want a hash, in which case you need to add `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end.

Answer (score 7):

Input

```
hash = {
  "ABC": {
    "attributes": {
      "id": "1",
      "from": "test",
      "to": "something",
    }
  },
  "XYZ": {
    "attributes": {
      "id": "1",
      "from": "value",
      "to": "another value",
    }
  }
}
```

Code

```
p hash.transform_values { |value| [value] }
```

Output

```
{:ABC=>[{:attributes=>{:id=>"1", :from=>"test", :to=>"something"}}], :XYZ=>[{:attributes=>{:id=>"1", :from=>"value", :to=>"another value"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
hashmap.each { |key, value| hashmap[key] = [hashmap[key]] }
```

where,
hashmap contains your original hash.

Comment: There are better methods such as `transform_values` that don't mutate the original hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
print items.transform_values { |item| [item] }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.